# How to specify element with same name but different values for different element in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an element in XML whose values can be different based on which element it is a part of. For example, consider below XML code

```
<element1>

    <action></action> //here action can have value -> add, delete

</element1>

<element2>

    <action></action> //here action can have value -> attach, detach

</element2>

<element3>

    <action></action> //here action can have value -> add, delete, attach, detach

</element3>
```

I need to write XSD for this but I was reading somewhere that this kind of scenario cannot be written in XSD. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**(Edit)**
I need something like this in my xsd. (Below XSD is not correct)

```
<xs:element name="e1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="action">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="Add"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="Delete"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="e2">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="action">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="Attach"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="Detach"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: I think what you want to do is fine, and is supported by XSD. As long as you only have a single action element in one complex type (e1, e2, etc) then you can restrict it's enumeration values on this basis. Why do you think your schema does not work? What XML instance are you trying to validate? Please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

XSD allows local element declarations as well as global declarations, and local declarations can have different types:

```
<xs:element name="e1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="action" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="e2">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="action" type="xs:dateTime"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

However, if two `action` elements can be siblings of each other, then they must have the same type (this constraint is called "element declarations consistent"). For example, you can't have an element with two children named `action` where the first is an `xs:integer` and the second is an `xs:dateTime`.

Comment: I need to give set of values to "action" element in e1 and e2 as well. I am unable to figure out that part. For e.g. I need something like this I have done in my edited question

Comment: I don't think the OP intends to have 2 action elements as siblings. Only that each action element can have a restricted set of values depending on which complex type (e1, e2, etc) it belongs to. Which is fine, right?

Comment: Well, instead of `xs:integer` and `xs:dateTime` you can obviously use your own user-defined simple types with different `xs:enumeration` facets. I just used those as examples since it seemed you were already familiar with defining your own enumeration types.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay . I created an XSD based on your instructions and it was working. I am posting it here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote following XSD based on what Michael Kay posted. It was working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="el1" type="el1Type"/>
        <xs:element name="el2" type="el2Type"/>
        <xs:element name="el3" type="el3Type"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="el1Type">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="action" type="el1ActionType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="el1ActionType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Add"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Delete"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="el2Type">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="action" type="el2ActionType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="el2ActionType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Attach"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Detach"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="el3Type">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="action" type="el3ActionType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="el3ActionType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Add"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Delete"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Attach"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Detach"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Corresponding XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <el1>
    <action>Add</action>
  </el1>
  <el2>
    <action>Attach</action>
  </el2>
  <el3>
    <action>Add</action>
  </el3>
</Root>
```